# Excel- Convert a N by 2 range into 2N by 1

Tags: excel

I have data of two columns

```
colA colB
123  456
124  457
```

I need insert `colB` into `colA`:

```
colA
123
456
124
457
```

I know how to do it via VBA, but is it possible to use **"basic" functions** to get it done?

All I can think of now is to create an ancillary col then do some sorting, and copy/paste. But I prefer  a "template" with auto-calculated formulas.

Comment: Load your data into Powerquery. It really is a single click to stack these rows. Once your data is in PQ you select both columns and go to "Transform" > "Unpivot". It doesn't get much easier than that.

Comment: If you really wanted formulas you could use something like `=INDEX(A:B,INT((ROWS($A$1:$A1)-1)/2)+1,MOD(ROWS($A$1:$A1)-1,2)+1)` copied down far enough to include your possible result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of Excel has these functions, you can use:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,$A$1:$B$2) & "</s></t>","//s")
```